# Is it safe to share my BTCGuild API key?

Tags: mining-pools, btcguild

Is there any risk in sharing my BTCGuild API key with someone else?  I want them to be able to see my hashing rate but I want to make sure it's not a bad idea or unsafe in anyway.

For example using this made up API key:
https://www.btcguild.com/api.php?api_key=a291130c92da4c27f4f2f69b89f63652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTCGuild doesn't seem to have a public documentation on their api so I may be wrong, but from what google searches are bringing up the API is used to access stats on your account. So unless you don't want people to know how much you've mined, you can safely share it (probably).